# "'$' is undefined" alert message shows

Tags: javascript, html, web

The following code always generates the `$ is undefined` alert message.

Here is the code for the Script tag:

```
function CheckString() {
  try {
    var s = "";
    s = $('#regExString').val();
    alert(s);
    var regExpression = /^[A-Z,a-z]\d[A-Z,a-z][\s{1}]?\d[A-Z,a-z]\d/;

    if (regExpression.test(s))
      alert("Valid postal code.");

    else
      alert("Invalid postal code.");

  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
  }
}
```

The html input text tag is passed as the text field and a button has this function (`CheckString`) as its on click function which validates the regular expression

Comment: have you included jquery library in your HTML file?

Comment: Where do you assign a value to *$*? It's not a built–in object.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `jQuery` has not been imported into your web solution.

In your HTML file in between your head tags, add this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: *$* is used by libraries other than jQuery.

Comment: Yes true, but the `val()` method here with an input box hints at jQuery being the library used here.